# Validators min and maximum number angular 4

Tags: forms, angular, validation

is there any option to make validator min and maximum number, i.e number between 0 to 200?

dialog-result-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialog, MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { FormGroup,FormControl,Validators,FormBuilder,  } from '@angular/forms';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-result',
  templateUrl: './dialog-result.component.html',
})

export class DialogResultComponent {


  form: FormGroup;
  name = new FormControl('',Validators.required);
  width = new FormControl('',Validators.required);
  height = new FormControl('',Validators.required);
  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogResultComponent>,private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
      'name':    this.name,
      'width':   this.width,
      'height':  this.height,
    });
}

  saveData(){
    this.dialogRef.close({name:this.name,width:this.width,height:this.height});
  }
}
```

dialog-result.component.html

```
       <form [formGroup]="form">
     <h3>MineSweeperwix</h3>
      <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
                <p><mdl-textfield type="text" label="name" formControlName="name" floating-label autofocus></mdl-textfield></p>
                <mdl-textfield type="number" formControlName="width" min="0" max="350" label="width"   floating-label autofocus></mdl-textfield>
               <mdl-textfield type="number" formControlName="height" label="height" min="0" max="350" floating-label autofocus  error-msg="'Please provide a correct email!'"></mdl-textfield>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
        <button mdl-button (click)="saveData()" mdl-button-type="raised" mdl-colored="primary" mdl-ripple [disabled]="!form.valid">Save</button>
        <button mdl-button (click)="dialogRef.close(dd)" mdl-button-type="raised" mdl-ripple>Cancel</button>
      </div>
   </form>
```

the min and maximum into the the mdl-text-field

```
min="0" max="200" floating-label autofocus
```

limit the user to write number between the range but it let to press the save button and that's not what i want to do. i want the user can press save button just if all the form is valid.

what I tried to do is

dialog.result.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialog, MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { FormGroup,FormControl,Validators,FormBuilder,ValidatorFn,AbstractControl  } from '@angular/forms';
import { NumberValidators } from '../validators/NumberValidators.module';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-result',
  templateUrl: './dialog-result.component.html',
})

export class DialogResultComponent {


  form: FormGroup;
  name = new FormControl('',Validators.required);
  width = new FormControl('',[Validators.required,NumberValidators.range(3,300)]);
  height = new FormControl('',[Validators.required,NumberValidators.range(3,300)]);
  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogResultComponent>,private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
      'name' :this.name,
      'width': this.width,
      'height':  this.height
    });
}

  saveData(){
    console.log(this.name.value);
    this.dialogRef.close({name:this.name.value,width:this.width.value,height:this.height.value});
  }

}
```

NumberValidators.module.ts

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export class NumberValidators {

    static range(min: number, max: number): ValidatorFn {
        console.log(min+max);
        return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
            if (c.value && (isNaN(c.value) || c.value < min || c.value > max)) {
                return { 'range': true };
            }
            return null;
        };
    }
```

}

but it's not works fine, anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write your own numeric validator. Something like this:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export class NumberValidators {

    static range(min: number, max: number): ValidatorFn {
        return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
            if (c.value && (isNaN(c.value) || c.value < min || c.value > max)) {
                return { 'range': true };
            }
            return null;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: hey Deborah, i took this validator and try to use it. it shows me an error . i used it like that                                                                                                      width = new FormControl('',Validators.required,NumberValidators.range(3,300));

Comment: it shows "argument of type ValidatorFn" is not assignable to parameter of type 'asynceValidatorFn .....

Comment: The second argument is for normal validators and the third argument is for async validators. This isn't an async validator. You need to add it as part of the second argument by passing the second argument as an array. Something like this: [validators.required, NumberValidators.range(3,300)]

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way I found is with validators. Check this reference link:

https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators

```
static min(min: number): ValidatorFn
static max(max: number): ValidatorFn
```

Complete code example which I have implemented is as following:

For the reference component.ts

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  'name' :new FormControl(null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
  'width':  new FormControl(null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(200)])),
  'height':  new FormControl(null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(200)]))
});
```

component.html

```
<div *ngIf="width.errors?.min || width.errors?.max" class="error">Width is not valid.</div>
<div *ngIf="height.errors?.min || height.errors?.max" class="error">Height is not valid.</div>
```