# Form Control isn't working for one of my input fields

Tags: html, angular

I have a registration form that has multiple input fields(username, email, password, confirm password). I set some form control on those fields like min length and stuff like that but for some reason it's working for all fields except the username.

Here's the username field:

```
<div class="form-control-group">
<label class="label" for="input-name">Username:</label>
<input nbInput
       [(ngModel)]="user.username"
       #username="ngModel"
       id="input-name"
       name="username"
       placeholder="Full name"
       autofocus
       fullWidth
       [status]="email.dirty ? (email.invalid  ? 'danger' : 'success') : ''"
       [required]="getConfigValue('forms.validation.username.required')"
       [minlength]="getConfigValue('forms.validation.username.minLength')"
       [maxlength]="getConfigValue('forms.validation.username.maxLength')"
       [attr.aria-invalid]="username.invalid && username.touched ? true : null">
<ng-container *ngIf="username.invalid && username.touched">
  <p class="error-message" *ngIf="username.errors?.required">
    Username is required!
  </p>
  <p class="error-message" *ngIf="username.errors?.minlength || username.errors?.maxlength">
    Username should contains
    from {{getConfigValue('forms.validation.username.minLength')}}
    to {{getConfigValue('forms.validation.username.maxLength')}}
    characters
  </p>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: check this reference answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43808780/validators-min-and-maximum-number-angular-4/47711133#47711133

Comment: What's not working? Can you please elaborate.

Comment: If I click on the username then switch to another input field it doesn't show me the username is required or if I enter a username shorter than 2 or longer than 10 it doesn't show me the minlength/maxlength error

Comment: Can you show us your user model? Could it be possible you are missing the username property? Also, are you sure you are not using another form control with your template controls? (this causes some weird issues). These are shots in the dark tbh, this template looks good as far as I can tell.

Comment: It looks like your model is bound to `user.username` where in your validation messages you have just `username`. So the value is getting bound to `user.username`, but you are checking just `username`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

blapaz answered it in the comments, but it looks like you just need to change your model binding. Currently, you have:

```
[(ngModel)]="user.username"
```

changing it to:

```
[(ngModel)]="username"
```

should solve your problem